# I am new at PHP , I am not able to connect my form with database . NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179:

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

**Please Help me with my form connection to database, table is created in database but i am confused how to connect it with my form **

> This is my how i am routing my form

```
      <div id="register" class="animate form">
                        <form action="{{route('signup')}}" method="post" autocomplete="on"> 
                            <h1> Sign up </h1>
```

> this is my controller

```
public function postSignup(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request['username'];
        $email = $request['email'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);


        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $username;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = $password;


        $user->save();
        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

and here comes my route file :

```
Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses' => UserController@postSignup,
    'as'=> 'signup'

    ]);
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCZgN.png)

Comment: simple typo error with method name `postSignup` method name .... method name should match in `'uses' => UserController@postSignup,` see you have upper case `S` in this and your method is in lower case `s` for signup

Comment: thats not a issue i have corrected it but nothing changed - it still says page not found .

Comment: can you post screenshot of the error page??

Comment: last line is the link for error screenshot

Comment: Is your .env file ok ? @saqlainshoaib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form like this:-

```
 <form action="{{url('signup')}}" method="post" autocomplete="on"> </from>
                                   Or
 <form action="{{ action('UserController@postSignup')}}" method="post" autocomplete="on"> </from>
```

And try this route:-

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/signup', 'UserController@postSignup');
```

Hope it helps!